# counting number of strings in a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

suppose I have a vector of string as follows

```
'1 2'
'1'
'1'
'1'
'1'
'1'
'1'
'1'
'1'
'1'
```

how can I obtain the frequency of the strings from this vector? Unique() isnt working and gives the error 
Error using cell/unique 
Input A must be a cell array of strings.

Comment: I have no idea where am I going wrong

Comment: So why not just use `unique(cellstr(...))`?

Comment: Error using cellstr 
Input must be a string.

Comment: @user2458552 In your example, do you want your frequency count for `1` to be 9 or 10?

Comment: it should be like- '1'-9, '1 2' -1 , '1 2 3' -0

Answer (score 4):

I guess you contain a non-char element in your vector. You should first convert your vector to a valid cellstr.

```
string_vector = your_vector(cellfun(@ischar, your_vector));
[unique_strings, ~, indices] = unique(string_vector);
frequencies = accumarray(indices(:), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Though kyamagu's answer looks like the simplest to follow, I am bringing this for the love of `bsxfun` and `vectorization` -

```
all_nums = char(INPUT_CELLARRAY);
unique_nums = unique(all_nums,'rows');
t1 = all_nums-'0';
t2 = permute(unique_nums-'0',[3 2 1]);
strings = cellstr(unique_nums)
count = squeeze(sum(all(bsxfun(@eq,t1,t2),2),1))
```

**Output**

```
strings = 

    '1'
    '1 2'


count =

     9
     1
```